# SQL Server 2008 insert/update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the stored procedure as shown below. At the moment it inserts a new row each time.

I want to change that so if cookie, domain, page, referrer, useragent, ipaddress match an existing row in the DB, and the datetimelast is within 10 seconds, it will update that row and set the datetimelast to current datetime, otherwise insert a new row as it does now.

Thanks

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[spJTrack]
(
   @cookie varchar(50) = null,
   @domain varchar(50) = null,
   @page varchar (MAX) = null,
   @referrer varchar (MAX) = null,
   @useragent varchar (MAX) = null,
   @ipaddress varchar (50) = null
)
AS
   INSERT INTO JTrack(cookie, domain, page, referrer, useragent, ipaddress, datetimestart, datetimelast) 
   VALUES (@cookie, @domain, @page, @referrer, @useragent, @ipaddress, GETDATE(), GETDATE())

   SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Look up the `MERGE` command.  And, if you want to capture the id of the row being inserted, the best way is with an `OUTPUT` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[spJTrack]
(
   @cookie varchar(50) = null,
   @domain varchar(50) = null,
   @page varchar (MAX) = null,
   @referrer varchar (MAX) = null,
   @useragent varchar (MAX) = null,
   @ipaddress varchar (50) = null
)
AS

if exists(select 1 from JTrack where cookie = @cookie and domain = @domain ...)
begin
 update JTrack
 set cookie = @cookie
 ......
 datetimelast = GETDATE()
 where condition
end
else
begin
INSERT INTO JTrack(cookie, domain, page, referrer, useragent, ipaddress, datetimestart, datetimelast) 
VALUES (@cookie, @domain, @page, @referrer, @useragent, @ipaddress, GETDATE(), GETDATE())
end
```